# How to adjust the font size of the message list and of the folder list in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, fontconfig

In Windows 10, I use Thunderbird 78.11.0 (32-Bit) as an e-mail client.

Today, suddenly the font size of the message list and of the folder list has become very small. (No changes in other applications).

How can I adjust the font size of the message list and of the folder list in Thunderbird?

Comment: Have you looked at Windows 10 scaling and text size. Settings, System  and then in Settings Search type in text size, or change size of text.   Make text bigger. I do both of the above.

Comment: Scaling and text size is OK for all my other apps. It's just Thunderbird.

Comment: I do not use Thunderbird, just Outlook, so I cannot assist with Thunderbird.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*Edit: As many have pointed out, there are now other answers that probably fit the constraints of the question better. My answer scales the whole interface including text, which very well may be sufficient for your needs. But if you want more fine-grain control, look to the other answers.*

Open the Menu and go to **Preferences > General**. Scroll all the way down and at the very bottom, click the **Config Editor...** button (accept the warning).

You're looking for **layout.css.devPixelsPerPx**, you can just search '*pixels*' and it'll show up.

Click on **layout.css.devPixelsPerPx** and edit the default value of -1.0 to a scale factor you are comfortable with (example: 1.5, 2.0, 2.25, etc).

Clicking  OK will allow you to immediately see your changes so you can dial it in pretty easily.

Comment: FANTASTIC - Thank you! A value of **1.3** made it just right. But now the LINE-HEIGHT in the Message List and in the Folder List is still too big. How can I decrease the line-height?

Comment: If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I have accepted the answer before, but mysteriously the accept check had disappeared. So now I accepted it again.

Comment: The scale factor is the only size adjustment I’m aware of without going in and editing the CSS or something. Unfortunately I can’t really help with that part.

Comment: Is there a CSS file located somewhere that is responsible for the Message List layout?

Comment: It looks like you might have to create it yourself. Read through this thread and note the linked tutorial in amanchesterman’s comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1137191

Comment: This is not a solution, this increases the size of everything.

Comment: @user1580348 please see my answer

Comment: This is a frankly ridiculous, having to go into about:config to adjust something this simple, but the good news is they are working on it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1715364

Comment: Thanks, it works for me :-)

Comment: It's a partial solution. It combines well with Mr. Rankin's solution.

Comment: This is no longer a correct answer. The [correct one](https://superuser.com/a/1810501/41709) is the one by @john-simmonds.

Answer (score 5):

This is the actual solution to your question. This was given in the Thunderbird support forum so it's not my production.

Try this css code:

```css
/* Threads Pane font and background*/
#threadTree > treechildren {
  font-size: 12pt !important;
  font-family: Times !important;
  background-color: lightgrey !important;
  color: navy !important;
}

/* Folder Pane font and background*/
#folderTree > treechildren {
  font-size: 12pt !important;
  font-family: Times !important;
  background-color: lightgrey !important;
  color: navy !important;
}
```

Help/Troubleshooting, Profile Folder, Open Folder, close TB, create a new folder named chrome, create a new document in chrome with a text editor, name it userChrome.css, Save as type: All files *.*, copy in the above code, change the numbers and colors as desired.  Double-click toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets to true in Options(Preferences)/General/Config. editor, restart TB.

Comment: This is the correct answer – the accepted answer will scale the body of the emails but *not* the font in the folder-list or message-list (actually, the only relevant lines within the CSS are the "font-size", font-family and colors are another matter)

Comment: Like the accepted solution, it's a partial solution. If you go too big with this, you lose sync with the gray bars.

Comment: This and the accepted solution complement each other well. Note that font-family can be whatever suits your taste (try Baskerville, Garamond, or Caslon, if available), but it is (at least running 102 on an M2 Mac with Ventura) completely ignored in the "folderTree" section (that whole section can be safely omitted). Also, "background-color" and "color" clauses can be safely omitted (they made it look terrible on my new Mac).

Comment: TB 115.3.3 doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 5):

I spent a couple of hours today trying to make `userChrome.css` work with Thunderbird 91 on Linux Mint.  No matter what I did the file was ignored.
I finally found the answer: go into the config editor and search for: `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`
and set that to `true`.  After doing that, the `userChrome.css` file works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Open the *"Burger Menu"* top right of the window.

Here you can change

- Font size and
- Density - Normal, Compact, or Touch.

I suggest changing the density to Normal to have more space and then increase the font size to something readable.

It can also be done from the *"View"* menu.

Comment: It's amusing that people are recommending Rube Goldberg solutions when it's exactly this simple!!

"Do <cntl>-<alt>-<meta>-<beta>-<tometa>-% while setting the control on your toaster to 'VERY VERY DARK' and changing the station on your TV to the Home Thunderbird Font Size Settings Channel."  

Comment: This is now the correct solution

Answer (score 3):

`layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` does not scale the fonts for me and I could not get it get `userChrome.css` to load.

What works like a charm is to set the environment variable `GDK_DPI_SCALE`

E.g.

```
$ GDK_DPI_SCALE=2 thunderbird
```